# Prettier add additional tabs

Tags: javascript, formatting, prettier, tsx, prettier-vscode

Prettier not adds an additional tab before the return and props declaration. Such formatting is in IntelliJ idea, how I can repeat it in vs code with prettier?

My prettier format files:

```
    return (     
        <Component
             Prop={123}
        /> 
    )
```

But I need it to be like this

```
    return (     
            <Component
                     Prop={123}
            /> 
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always increase the [`--tab-width`](https://prettier.io/docs/en/options.html#tab-width) option to get larger indents. Hower, if you want to keep the line breaks exactly like that I'm afraid this is too specific for Prettier. It will wrap lines differently.

If you want to keep one particular line untouched by Prettier use a [`// prettier-irgnore`](https://prettier.io/docs/en/ignore.html) commend. E. g.

```
...
  // prettier-ignore
  return (     
            <Component
                     Prop={123}
            /> 
   )
...
```

Comment: Tabs cannot be increased since they should be 4, but there should be an additional tab before the return and the declaration of the props